# lateinit property has not been initialized with dagger and coroutine

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, dagger-2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying MVVM, Dagger2, Retrofit and Coroutine. Now I have the problem that I can successfully inject a `ProfileService` into my activity, but not into my repository. I get a `profileService lateinit property has not been initialized`

```
//MainActivity
@Inject
lateinit var profileService: ProfileService //only for testing

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val getTheExpectedResult = profileService.hasValidName("asdffff") //true
    profileViewModel.createProfile("ku") //throw the not initialized
}
```

The viewmodel calls the repository.

```
// profile repository
private fun getProfileRepository(userId: String = "", apiKey: String = ""): ProfileRepository {
    return ProfileRepository(ApiFactory.getApi(userId, apiKey))
}

fun createProfile(name: String) {
    scope.launch {
        try {
            val profile = getProfileRepository().createProfile(name)
            profileLiveData.postValue(profile)
        }
//...
```

In the repository I inject the `profileService`

```
class ProfileRepository(private val api: NIPApiInterface) {
@Inject
lateinit var profileService: ProfileService

suspend fun createProfile(name: String): ProfileResponse? {
    if (!profileService.hasValidName(name)) { //throw the not initialized
//...
```

My unspectacular `ProfileService`

```
class ProfileService @Inject constructor() {
 fun hasValidName(name: String): Boolean {
    return name.length > 3
 }
}
```

So that I don't post too much code, the following info. In my `Application` I seem to initialize everything correctly, because the `Activity` can access the `ProfileService`. Here are my Dagger configurations:

```
//AppComponent
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class
    ]
)

interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<NIPApplication> {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: NIPApplication): AppComponent
    }
}
```

The `AppModule`

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(app: NIPApplication): Context = app
}
```

If you need more code, please send a comment.

Comment: You don't show where/how you initialize `profileViewModel` but you say it's not initialized and throws an exception when accessed... Did you forget to create your ViewModel? Otherwise please include the stacktrace as well as the code it references

Answer (score 1):

Dagger won't inject dependencies unless it creates an instance of a class that needs injection or is explicitly asked to. Since the `ProfileRepository` object is created by you, it won't get its dependencies injected by Dagger.

The best way to solve this is to let Dagger create `ProfileRepository` objects by `@Inject`-annotated constructor (or using `@Provides`-annotated method in a Dagger module (provider), however this seems quite redundant in this particular case):

```
class ProfileRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: NIPApiInterface, 
    private val profileService
)
```

Note that now Dagger will want to inject an `NIPApiInterface` object as well, so you have to create a provider for that or remove it from the constructor and pass it in some other way.